# Caching in Apigee using proxy.basepath

Tags: apigee

I have created a new API `/v1/StatusCache` to point to my end point `/v1/Status`.  My goal is to be able to cache the data :

1. based on the uri
2. for a particular header

So if user 1 sends request to `/v1/StatusCache/1234` and the same user sends request to `/v1/StatusCache/5678`, I should hit my server instead of getting previously cached result from the first request.

Also we user header (Authorization: Bearer ) in the request so my second goal is that if user 1 with header Authorization: Bearer token1 sends a request to `/v1/StatusCache/1234` vs a user 2 with header Authorization: Bearer token2 sends a request to `/v1/StatusCache/1234`, I should get different results (non cached results)

I have this code for proxypath but it just caches every request for 10 seconds.  What am I missing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ResponseCache async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="responsecache-1">
    <DisplayName>ResponseCache-1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <CacheKey>
        <Prefix/>
        <KeyFragment ref="proxy.pathsuffix" type="string">proxy.pathsuffix</KeyFragment> 
    </CacheKey>
    <Scope>Exclusive</Scope>
    <ExpirySettings>
        <ExpiryDate/>
        <TimeOfDay/>
        <TimeoutInSec ref="">10</TimeoutInSec>
    </ExpirySettings>
    <SkipCacheLookup/>
    <SkipCachePopulation/>
</ResponseCache>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be create a variable value combining the header and pathsuffix value (header+pathsuffix) - use this as the key for the response cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ResponseCache async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="responsecache-1">
    <DisplayName>ResponseCache-1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <CacheKey>
        <Prefix/>
        <KeyFragment ref="proxy.pathsuffix" type="string"/>
      <KeyFragment ref="request.header.Authorization" type="string"/>
    </CacheKey>
    <ExpirySettings>
        <ExpiryDate/>
        <TimeOfDay/>
        <TimeoutInSec ref="">60</TimeoutInSec>
    </ExpirySettings>
    <SkipCacheLookup/>
    <SkipCachePopulation/>
</ResponseCache>
```

I used 60 sec timeout for ease of testing.

This shows an example of `proxy.pathsuffix` + `request.header.Authorization` values being a unique cache key.  Think of the key now looking like `/1234__Bearer token1`.  The same path suffix and Authorization header value combined are needed to return an entry from cache.

Also, when trying to cache the URI, you may want to try the variable `request.uri` which includes the querystring-- this can sometimes dictate what the response looks like.  If using this, be sure that the querystring does not include unique values like a current timestamp (or at least strip that parameter before using it as a cache key fragment).